# MySQL - get count of users based on weeks of login history

Tags: mysql

There are two tables - `users` and `login_history`.

```
----------------------------------------------
-- user_id -- | -- created -------------------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-01 13:07:24 -------
--  2  ------ | -- 2018-12-01 13:08:24 -------
--  3  ------ | -- 2019-01-01 13:09:24 -------
--  4  ------ | -- 2019-02-01 13:10:24 -------
--  5  ------ | -- 2019-02-01 13:11:24 -------
----------------------------------------------
```

The below query returns the count of the above users based on `YEAR` and `MONTH` of when they were created.

```
SELECT MONTH(created) as monthly, YEAR(created) as yearly, 
       count(*) as new_users FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(created),MONTH(created)
ORDER BY YEAR(created) DESC, MONTH(created) DESC
```

which returns the below data that shows 1 user each created in month of November, December of 2018, January of 2019 and 2 users created in month of February 2019 :

```
------------------------------------
----monthly---yearly----new_users---
----11--------2018-------1----------
----12--------2018-------1----------
----1---------2019-------1----------
----2---------2019-------2----------
------------------------------------
```

Another table `login_history` keeps the record of the user logins in the system which shows that user with `user_id` logged in 5 times in November of 2018, 2 times each in December 2018, January 2019 and February 2019:

```
----------------------------------------------
-- user_id -- | -- login_time ----------------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-01 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-02 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-09 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-10 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-11-21 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-12-01 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-12-11 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2019-01-01 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-01-05 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-02-01 13:07:24 -------
--  1  ------ | -- 2018-02-07 13:07:24 -------
----------------------------------------------
```

Now based on the similar data set, I have to get the count of users who when created in a particular month of a year, logged in to the system again in the first week, then second week, then third and so on.... till the 5th week.

I have changed the sample data set to be larger and the output should be as below i.e 100 new users that were created in November of 2018, 98 of 100 logged in the week 1, 80 of 100 in week 2 and so on...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----monthly---yearly----new_users-------week1------week2----week3------week4-----week5----
----11--------2018-------100-------------98---------80-------60---------70--------10------
----12--------2018-------200-------------190--------150------120--------100-------30------
----1---------2019-------300-------------288--------250------200--------100-------50------
----2---------2019-------400-------------360--------200-------100--------50-------5-------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I have tried so far is below but i couldn't get the week numbers as such:

```
SELECT t1.monthly, t1.yearly, t1.total as total_users, t2.total as logins from (
SELECT user_id, count(*) as total, YEAR(created) as yearly, MONTH(created) as monthly FROM users
GROUP BY user_id, YEAR(created),MONTH(created)
ORDER BY YEAR(created) DESC, MONTH(created) DESC) t1
join (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as total from login_history
GROUP BY user_id) t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query returns a data set which shows how many users logged in the subsequent weeks.

```
SELECT
 MONTH(u.created) as monthly, YEAR(u.created) as yearly, count(DISTINCT u.user_id) as new_users,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN u.created AND (u.created + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN  u.user_id END) AS week1,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week2,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week3,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 3 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 3 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week4,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 4 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 4 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week5,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 5 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 5 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week6,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 6 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 6 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week7,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 7 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 7 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week8,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 8 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 8 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week9,
 COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lh.login_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 9 WEEK) AND ( DATE_ADD(u.created, INTERVAL 9 WEEK) + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) THEN u.user_id END) AS week10 
 FROM
  users as u
LEFT JOIN
  login_history as lh
    ON u.user_id = lh.user_id
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(u.created), MONTH(u.created)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(u.created) DESC, MONTH(u.created) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Output as :

```
monthly, yearly, new_users, week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7, week8, week9, week10
3, 2019, 1418, 676, 131, 107, 55, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 2019, 1452, 707, 241, 234, 239, 202, 157, 93, 32, 2, 0
1, 2019, 2664, 1178, 469, 404, 359, 332, 316, 284, 321, 321, 214
12, 2018, 1574, 340, 50, 88, 53, 17, 47, 50, 29, 48, 19
11, 2018, 1608, 689, 138, 97, 84, 87, 76, 46, 55, 51, 54
10, 2018, 5349, 1817, 763, 691, 656, 585, 531, 478, 465, 455, 422
9, 2018, 5318, 2959, 1295, 1330, 1172, 1101, 1137, 1099, 971, 913, 917
8, 2018, 209, 73, 11, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 12, 10, 8
7, 2018, 223, 57, 7, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
6, 2018, 172, 62, 11, 6, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0
```